# Marquee tag not working properly in IOS platform

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used marquee to display breaking news.Its working in all browsers in android and windows but not in IOS platform.I need to replace the marquee tag with Html.Could you please suggest me any way to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might better have googled this, as I did: https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/ticker/

Answer (score 2):

Marquee has been deprecated since a while.

Refer this link for more info

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee